# How to alphabetically sort values in a pandas column that is a list

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I had a question about sorting values in a list in a dataframe.  I have sales order data with about 3000 rows.  A sales order can contain one or multiple inventory items. I reshaped my data and was able to create a dataset like this:

Current result:

| sales_order | bundle |
| --- | --- |
| so-1 | apple, pear, tomato |
| so-2 | bread, fish |
| so-3 | fish, bread |
| so-4 | pear, tomato, apple |
| so-5 | tomato |

I would like to sort each 'bundle' value alphabetically by row, so I can group the resulting string, quantify, and visualize in tableau against other data in my dataframe, but am having trouble doing so.

I tried various things like a lambda function and 'sort', but that ruined the data.  I also tried using sort values on the bundle column, and this helped in certain ways, but did not sort the items in the list alphabetically.

| sales_order | bundle |
| --- | --- |
| so-1 | apple, pear, tomato |
| so-2 | bread, fish |
| so-3 | bread, fish |
| so-4 | apple, pear, tomato |
| so-5 | tomato |

is there any way to parse through each 'bundle' column value and sort the value alphabetically?

I did try
z = df.copy()
z = z['bundle'].sort_values()

this works for my sample data I provided in this question, but only because the data is oversimplified.  It doesnt work on my actual data.

here is an example where the sort_values is not sorting my data:

```
    testdf = pd.DataFrame({'sales_order': ['so-1','so-2'],\
    'Inv_item': ['Revolve 3 Clean 110cm,Resolution 3 Glare - 120bp- Normal viscosity',\
    'Resolution 3 Glare - 120bp - Normal viscosity,Revolve 3 Clean 110cm']})

    testdf['Inv_item'].sort_values()

    1    Resolution 3 Glare - 120bp - Normal viscosity,...
    0    Revolve 3 Clean 110cm,Resolution 3 Glare - 120...
    Name: Inv_item, dtype: object
```

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below to sort each value:

```
df['bundle'].str.split(', ').map(sorted).str.join(', ')
```

Another option is to use `frozenset` which can be used in `groupby()` It wont sort your values, but could be useful.

```
df['bundle'].str.split(', ').map(frozenset)
```

Output:

```
0    apple, pear, tomato
1            bread, fish
2            bread, fish
3    apple, pear, tomato
4                 tomato
```